# Update older records column when a new record is added

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a **last** column. When adding a new record to the table, by default, **last** = 1. I need that when adding a new record, the old records have the value **last** = 0.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Why?. Data is SQL is unordered by default. Why not just have an insert timestamp field and query by max(insert_ts)?

Comment: Your question appears to be an *XY Problem*. See: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What are you actually needing to do?

Comment: I need to mark the last entry somehow.

Comment: use the current timestamp when you create a new record. With this information you can later order the records and find the last record.